# SQL SP4 installed but not showing @@version

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install `SQL Server 2005 SP4` on `windows 2008 R2 SP1`. Right now I have `SQL Server 2005 x64 Standard Edition SP1`. I did try to install the `SP 4` couple of times but whenever I checked the `@@version` it’s still showing me `SP1`. 
I download this version of `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4 RTM` and trying to install with no luck.
I check the hotfix summary and its shows me below results:

```
******************
Prerequisites Check & Status
SQLSupport: Passed
*******************
Products Disqualified & Reason
Product                                   Reason
*******************
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the installation of sp4 completed succesfully? did you get any message at the end of the pack installation?

Comment: Try to use TSQL command - from that string google and you will see actual version + all patches (`select @@VERSION`). For example [here](http://sqlserverversions.blogspot.bg/).

Comment: moreover don't expect to find the string 'SP4' in the output of `@@version`, it does not works that way.

Comment: Thats why I write "google it".

Comment: Or [here](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.bg/) - this is better because it shows mayor versions. So lets say you got `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)` you need this string (`11.0.2100.60`) to find exact version of your SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ServicePack
GO
```